# How to unit test a private method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am new to unit testing and i don't know how to test a private method?

Is there is any way to test a private method **?**

I am using MSTest framework.

**Private Method Code:**

```
private int IncreasePoints(int userPoints)
{
   if (userPoints > 0 && userPoints < 50)
      userPoints += 0;

   else if (userPoints >= 50 && userPoints < 100)        
      userPoints += 10;

   else if (userPoints == 100)
      userPoints += 15;

   else if (userPoints > 100)
      userPoints += 25;

   else
      userPoints += 0;

   return userPoints;
}
```

Comment: check this : https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/dhananjay_kumar/posts/how-to-unit-test-private-methods-in-ms-test

Comment: In short... Don't unit test private methods.  Test the exposed functionality of an object.  Unit tests are consuming code just like any other consuming code, they shouldn't know or care about the implementation details.  And the more coupled they are to those details, the more brittle they are when those details change.  If refactoring your class requires you to re-write your tests then that breaks the red-green-refactor cycle.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Thanks.. https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/dhananjay_kumar/posts/how-to-unit-test-private-methods-in-ms-test  Worked for me....